# Date picker is not working on a dynamic element - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

Datepicker is working on a static element

```
 $('#SSL_CALEN_ID').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    autoClose: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
  })
```

But not working on a dynamic element. Please find the code below:

```
 $('body').on('focus', "[name='expDate']", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(this.id); //ID OF THE TEXT BOX IS GETTING ALERTED
    $(this).datepicker({
      language: 'en',
      autoClose: true,
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    })
  });
```

While performing the alert, the `id` of the text box is getting alerted but the calendar is not getting popped up. Can you please point the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to initiate the date picker at the point the input is added to the page - by the time you focus on it, it will be too late (plus the way you do it will initialise the datepicker every time you focus on the input, which is not good)

Comment: Initiate datepicker on dynamic elements right after they're created... And do it just like you do for static elements.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I am a beginner. can you please guide me how to do this. Thank you so much.

Comment: How are the `expDate` elements created?

Comment: I am adding a template (Handlebars) to the existing web page and I intend to use datepicker on that.

Comment: Okay... I think your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645870/datepicker-inside-a-handlebars-template)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datepicker inside a handlebars template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645870/datepicker-inside-a-handlebars-template)